# Will Linux servers running NTPD be affected by plans to add a leap second in 2015?

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

I [have read](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/11327571/Leap-second-French-time-lords-add-one-second-to-2015.html) that there are plans to add a leap second in June 2015. At work we are running a number of Linux (Ubuntu) servers with `ntpd` installed to keep the time in sync and correct across them.

Does anybody know how this time change will affect us, i.e. whether or not we need to do anything other than just let `ntpd` correct the time for us?

I can find no information on the sites for either [NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) or [NTPD](http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpd.htm).

For context, we run PHP/Apache/Solr/MySQL servers, and interact with third-party APIs that supply time-dependent responses, such as historical exchange rates or geolocations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leap seconds are inserted regularly, and no, you don't have to expect any problems or do anything because of it.

If you're interested in the details of how NTP handles them, there's a write-up of it [here](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/leap.html). In a nutshell, NTP freezes time during a leap second, so there'll be (sort of) a second that's two times as long as usual.

Comment: NTP freezes time, the Kernel doesnt. And yes in the past there have been problems with leap seconds at it is likely that new bugs come up this time as well.